# Linux (Android): how to disable Intel DPST (Display Power Saving Technology) - i915 driver

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have an Android tablet (Teclast X98) with an extremely annoying feature that it constantly keeps adjusting the brightness of the display all by itself.

Initially I thought maybe the tablet has a faulty display unit - the pumping of the brightness is that annoying. After a lot of investigation I finally noticed this in `dmesg`:

```
QL: i915_dpst_compute_brightness dpst factor = 7022.
QL: i915_dpst_compute_brightness dpst factor = 6987.
QL: i915_dpst_compute_brightness dpst factor = 6882.
```

Put DPST into Google and I find the Intel engineers came up with this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Display_Power_Saving_Technology

So it's not just the brightness that is adjusted, but also the chroma of the display, which leads to washed out colors in addition to the reduced backlight intensity.

Next I try and find the driver where this is implemented. Giving the function name a shot on GitHub I [found it in the i915 GPU driver](https://github.com/ZenfoneArea/android_kernel_asus_zenfone5/blob/a4e0cedc20af95f1583a46e53ff4448855bb2a9f/linux/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_dpst.c#L256).

Now I see in that the driver has a `dpst.enabled` setting.

Presumably there should be some way to set `dpst.enabled` to `false`.

Anyone have any clue how I could turn it off?
`sysctl`, `/proc/...`? There has to be some way to turn it off?

Comment: FWIW, DPST is not part of the [upstream i915 driver](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/drm-intel). What you found on GitHub is a derivative, specific to some of the Android products out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. That was surprisingly easy.
Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but here's how I got rid of it:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/drm/card0/power/i915_dpst

# Something keeps writing 1 into this file, so I just prevent it like this
busybox chmod gou-w /sys/class/drm/card0/power/i915_dpst
```

If someone knows a better way to disable it please add an answer.

Comment: Presumably you have already tried unchecking automatic adjustments in the settings menu?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes. There are no settings for this in any of the settings menus.

Comment: For me, this prints `bash: /sys/class/drm/card0/power/i915_dpst: No such file or directory`. What could be wrong?

Comment: @pratyaksh Is this a Teclast X98 also? Try to follow the path in your shell `cd /sys/class/drm` and see what you find there. It could be named something else (but probably a similar name). Maybe `busybox find /sys/class -iname \*dpst`?

Comment: @Casper oops, I'm on a ubuntu notebook!

Comment: @pratyaksh Well if you have an i915 display driver then maybe the dpst setting is still there somewhere. Try the `find` command on `/sys`, but maybe it could be available somewhere directly in the display settings of the Ubuntu GUI. Here it is on Windows: http://superuser.com/questions/414622/how-to-disable-auto-brightening-lcd

Comment: @pratyaksh Also note Jani's comment up there saying DPST is not part of the upstream driver, but only on Android. Perhaps it's not turned on at all on your notebook.